# Add to favourites and view from favourites with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I have a state

```
const [ideas, setIdeas] = useState([{title:"test", favourite:false]);
```

Component `Idea.jsx` returns `props.title` and a button **"fav"**.

`App.jsx` maps through the `idea[]` and renders each `idea.title` in

```
<Item title = {idea.title}/>
```

on the page.

**Problem:**
Every time when **"fav"** is clicked I want to toggle `ideas[index].favourite`.
How to change a value of `favourite` only for an `idea` that was clicked?

How to add this exact `idea` to the array `favourites[]`?

**App.jsx**

```
   function App() {

const [ideas, setIdeas] = useState([{title:"test", 
favourite:false}]);

const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)

function showAllIdeas () {
setIsClicked(prevValue => {
return !prevValue
}
)
}
function mapIdeas(){return ideas.map((ideaItem, index) => {
    return (<Idea
          key = {index}
         id = {index}
         title = {ideaItem.title} 
     />
     
     );
 })}

 return ( <div>


 <Fab  color="primary" onClick={showAllIdeas}>{expandText()}</Fab>
 {isClicked && mapIdeas()}

 </div>)
 }
```

**Item.jsx**

```
function Idea(props) {

const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)

function handleClick(){

 setIsClicked(prevValue => {
    return !prevValue  
 })
}
 console.log(isClicked)

return(
<div className={"idea-list" } ><p>{props.title} {isClicked ? 
<StarIcon onClick={handleClick}/> :<StarBorderIcon onClick=. 
{handleClick}/>}</p>

</div>

)
}
```

Comment: You should add the code snippet.

Comment: See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sara-0by13?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleFavToggle = (index) => {
   setItems(items=> {
      const data = [...items]
      data[index] = {...data[index],favourite: !data[index].favourite }
      return data
   })
}

<Item key={index} title={item.title} index={index} handleFavToggle={handleFavToggle}/>
```

In item component you have to handle click with handleFavToggle and pass all params